# Access Client Write Key & Server Write Key from OpenSSL C API

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, key

I have a need to access the encryption (cipher, write) keys that are generated from the master key that is generated from the OpenSSL C API.  I know I can access the master key using the SSL struct as follows:

```
ssl->session->master_key
```

Unfortunately looking at the OpenSSL code has not gotten me very far as the API is not very well documented and looking at GDB has been a pain as well.  Are they exposed anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am working on the same thing as well.
Well for the SSlv3 connections, you can access the key block by,

```
ssl->s3->tmp.key_block
```

However, I managed to get this at the end of ssl3_setup_key_block method which is defined in s3_enc.c file. I mean I changed the source code and recompiled openssl. So I don't know yet if it changes or becomes lost after returning from that function.

This key block is a string and as defined in http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt its structure is;

```
{

clientWriteMACSecret,

  serverWriteMACSecret,

  clientWriteKey,

  serverWriteKey,

  clientWriteIV,

  serverWriteIV

}
```

The length of each section varies depending on the used cipher suite.

For SSLv2 connections I suppose you can again access these areas by calling `ssl->s2->something` as well. s2 is an object of `ssl2_state_st` structure which is defined in ssl2.h. You can look that up from there.

I don't know how it is for TLSv1 connections. But there is also a d1 variable in the SSL structure.

As a personal note, openssl source code is really a bunch of trash. No good code comments, no good documentation. Wandering inside the source code in order to find the simplest thing is a pain.